# Request fails to authenticate when password contains '@'

Tags: python, python-requests

This is simple python script : when password contains "@" request failed with error

```
ip = "XX.XX.XX.XX"

username='admin'

password = "kdsjkj@dfdsa"

headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "accept": "application/json"}

params = {}

params["username"] = username

params["password"] = password

baseurl = "https://ip:port/storagemgr/rest"

r = requests.post(baseurl,params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

output :

```
description:An error occurs to the parameter

suggestion:Enter a correct parameter
```

Same things works properly on curl command

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"admin","password":"x@xxx"}' https://xx.xx.xx.xx:/storagemgr/rest
```

Can you kindly suggest any solution. i have tried with proxy it is not working.

Comment: Are you actually using the string `"https://ip:port/storagemgr/rest"` as your baseurl or are you substituting the correct values in?

Comment: Also what is the actual code that is running? Nothing here gives that output. Do you get an exception with more information in?

Comment: Here's a suggestion, you could post the code that does the password verification.

Comment: i have written baseurl, but using substitute ip and port value in base url.

Comment: vagrant@cp102:~$ python try.py                                                                                 
{u'data': {}, u'error': {u'code': 50331651, u'description': u'An error occurs to the parameter.', u'suggestion': u'Enter a correct parameter.'}}
<Response [200]>
output:u'{"data":{},"error":{"code":50331651,"description":"An error occurs to the parameter.","suggestion":"Enter a correct parameter."}}\n'
Operation was completed.
vagrant@cp102:~$

Comment: This is the script i am using : I have replaced IP. It is sample script.

Comment: headers = {"content-type": "application/json",
           "accept": "application/json"}

ip = “X.X.X.X”
username = "admin"
password = “nbbnhj@shjhj”
baseurl = "https://%s:8088/deviceManager/rest" % ip
params = {}
params["username"] = username
params["password"] = password 
params["scope"] = 0 
try: 
    r = requests.post(baseurl + "/xxxxx/sessions",params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
    version = r.json()
    print version
    pprint.pprint(r)
    pprint.pprint(r.text)

Answer (score 0):

Your python request is wrongly configured.  You are sending url-encoded url parameters instead of a json body.

Look what at the responses when the requests are echoed by [httpbin.org](http://httpbin.org/)'s `post` endpoint.

#### curl (correct)

```
$  curl -k -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"foo","password":"b@r"}' http://httpbin.org/post  
                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                    
  "args": {},                                                                                                                        
  "data": "{\"username\":\"foo\",\"password\":\"b@r\"}",                                                                             
  "files": {},                                                                                                                       
  "form": {},                                                                                                                        
  "headers": {                                                                                                                       
    "Accept": "*/*",                                                                                                                 
    "Connection": "close",                                                                                                           
    "Content-Length": "35",                                                                                                          
    "Content-Type": "application/json",                                                                                              
    "Host": "httpbin.org",                                                                                                           
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.37.0"                                                                                                      
  },                                                                                                                                 
  "json": {                                                                                                                          
    "password": "b@r",                                                                                                               
    "username": "foo"                                                                                                                
  },                                                                                                                                 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",                                                                                                        
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"                                                                                                   
}
```

Observe the `json` element of the response contains the expected values.

#### requests (wrong)

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "accept": "application/json"}
>>> params = {'username': 'foo', 'password': 'b@r'}

>>> r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {
    "password": "b@r", 
    "username": "foo"
  }, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "0", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.4"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post?username=foo&password=b%40r"
}
```

Observe the `data` and `json` elements are empty, and that the authentication parameters are in the url.

#### requests (correct)

To fix the request, pass `params` as the `json` argument to `requests.post`, so it is set as the request body.

```
>>> r = requests.post(url, json=params, headers=headers)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"username\": \"foo\", \"password\": \"b@r\"}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "38", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.12.4"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "password": "b@r", 
    "username": "foo"
  }, 
  "origin": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```